# Ng-model on input element not working

Tags: angularjs, input, angular-ngmodel

I have input elements and want to get their values in controller, but the object ng-model is always empty. Check in

`jsFiddle:` http://jsfiddle.net/MSjqL/123/

Comment: both inputs are disabled. you can't change the model in the fiddle you provided. the inputs start as empty and they stay empty because of it.
check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7k8xxdoj/1

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to access text entered in input boxes then you need to remove disabled attributes on input elements.

I have it working over here 
`jsFiddle:` http://jsfiddle.net/MSjqL/129/

Answer (score -1):

To get the value of an `input` element, you can use the `angular.element` method: http://jsfiddle.net/MSjqL/125/

Alternatively, you can use vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.findElementById('...').attributes.value;
```

or jQuery:

```
$('...').val();
```

Comment: This is angular-related question. If the input is bound via 2 way binding to the model inside the controller it should be updated with the value entered.